# Bootstrap place second column under first on phone

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.4 with the below code in the page. This works perfectly on a desktop browser but when you view on a mobile phone the sidebar is squeezed very narrow vertical. What I would like is for the sidebar column to move under the MainContent column. Is this possible?

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
          <MainContent />
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <RightSideBar />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the small grid breakpoint...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <MainContent />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <RightSideBar />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. That seems to work for phone, but how does it work for devices between a phone and a desktop browser?